# Openpyxl Python Module Downloaded but Not Working

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I have downloaded the Opexpyxl Module with

```
sudo pip3 install openpyxl
```

and it says

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

So I know it has been downloaded, but when I try to use the module with `import openpyxl` with python in the terminal I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I have the Raspberry Pi 4b, running python version 3.8.0
How can I get this working?

Comment: You have installed Python 3.8 but you've installed the module with pip for Python 3.7, the one provided by the OS. You need to either stick to Python 3.7, invoke pip for 3.8 (`python3.8 -m pip install xxx`) or upgrade to Bullseye which has Python 3.9. Installing packages for non-system Python can be laborious, and wheels are provided for system ones by piwheels.org but not non-system ones like 3.8.

Comment: Further note, I know it is installed because after doing 'pip list' I can see I have version 3.0.9

Comment: @ben_nuttall I followed up https://www.piwheels.org based on your comment above and found the site intriguing. It really deserves more public exposure although I just found https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#installing-python-libraries it is pretty well hidden.

Comment: Just now I installed smoothly openPyXl 3.0.9 (and also et_xmlfie) on my Pi Pico and my microPython program can import openPyXl without any error messages.  But I need to further install the Decimal package.